# How to use latex code to output a triangular pattern like this?

Tags: pdftex, formatting, matrices, pattern

[image]

[image]

(The Gelfand pattern on some paper.)
I have tried to use align and my code is

```latex
\begin{align} 
\left(
\begin{aligned}
\lambda_{1d}& &\lambda_{2d}& &\cdots& &\lambda_{d-1,d}& &\lambda_{d,d}\\
& \lambda_{1,d-1}& & \lambda_{2,d-1}& & \cdots& & \lambda_{d-1,d-1}&\\
& & & &\cdots& & & & \\
& & &\ \lambda_{12}& &\ \lambda_{22}& & &\\
& & & &\lambda_{11}& & & &\\ 
\end{aligned}
\right)
\end{align}
```

and the output is[image]

Is seems overfull and ill formatted. How can I improve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions. The first employs an `array` environment and the `w` column type to force all 11 columns to have the same width, which is determined by the need to fit in the element `\lambda_{n-1,n-1}`. The second solution employs a `pmatrix` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package). As most cells are sonsiderably more compact than `\lambda_{n-1,n-1}`, the overall width of the matrix is quite a bit less than that of the array employed in the first solution.

Which solution you prefer is up to you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{array}    % for 'w' column type
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'pmatrix' environment
\newlength\mylen 

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{-3pt} % very tight spacing
\settowidth\mylen{$\lambda_{n-1,n-1}$} % determine column width
\left(\begin{array}{@{\hspace{-8pt}} *{11}{wc{\mylen}} @{\hspace{-8pt}}}
\lambda_{1n} &      & \lambda_{2n} &        &        & \dots  &        & &  \lambda_{n-1,n} &             & \lambda_{n,n} \\
             & \lambda_{1,n-1} &   & \lambda_{2,n-1} &        &        & & \dots  &           & \lambda_{n-1,n-1} \\
             &      &        &     &        & \dots  \\
             &      &        &     & \lambda_{12} &  & \lambda_{22} \\   
             &      &        &     &        & \lambda_{11} \\ 
\end{array}\right)
\]

\bigskip
\[
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{11} % default value: 10
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_{1n} &      & \lambda_{2n} &        &        & \dots  &        & &  \lambda_{n-1,n} &             & \lambda_{n,n} \\
             & \lambda_{1,n-1} &   & \lambda_{2,n-1} &        &        & & \dots  &           & \lambda_{n-1,n-1} \\
             &      &        &     &        & \dots  \\
             &      &        &     & \lambda_{12} &  & \lambda_{22} \\   
             &      &        &     &        & \lambda_{11} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used a pmatrix environment and it performs much better, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can read the doc of `tabularray` section 5.1.

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{+pmatrix}[columns={colsep=1pt}]
\lambda_{1d} &                 & \lambda_{2d} &                 & \cdots       &              & \lambda_{d-1,d} &                   & \lambda_{d,d} \\
             & \lambda_{1,d-1} &              & \lambda_{2,d-1} &              & \cdots       &                 & \lambda_{d-1,d-1} &               \\
             &                 &              &                 & \cdots       &              &                 &                   &               \\
             &                 &              & \lambda_{12}    &              & \lambda_{22} &                 &                   &               \\
             &                 &              &                 & \lambda_{11} &              &                 &                   &               \\
\end{+pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the textual ellipsis in row 2 (produced by `\cdots`) be in a column of its own? (The OP's own code appears to make the same mistake.)

Comment: @Mico Let the OP adjust themselves without affecting their understanding of the implementation method.

Answer (score 1):

With `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{11}
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
\lambda_{1n} &                 & \lambda_{2n} &                 &              & \dots        &             & \lambda_{n-1,n} &                   & \lambda_{n,n} \\
             & \lambda_{1,n-1} &              & \lambda_{2,n-1} &              &              &             &                 & \lambda_{n-1,n-1} \\
             &                 &              &                 &              & \dots \\
                         \\
             &                 &              &                 & \lambda_{12} &              & \lambda_{22} \\   
             &                 &              &                 &              & \lambda_{11} \\ 
\CodeAfter 
  \line{2-2}{5-5}
  \line{2-9}{5-7}
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you for your share, but it seems that i cannot compile the code on overleaf and it report a mistake that \CodeAfter and \line are undefined control sequence.

Comment: You are probably working with an Overleaf project which uses an old version of TeXLive. I have tried on Overleaf with TeX Live 2022 (in the "menu") and it works.